# BotFramework - strictFilters to filter QnAMaker results

Tags: botframework

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#qna-maker-samples

Currently, we have a few values in the metadata on questions to answer based on location.

In these examples, there isn't a way to use the strictFilters options to filter out the FAQs from QnAMaker.

How would I edit the QnAMakerCustomDialog.cs I currently have in order to add in the strictFilters? It is currently set to null and I have tried a few different ways to add filters, but they return syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter based on metadata associated with the QnA pair that you applied in the qnamaker.ai portal, you simply need to use the 2nd parameter in `QnAMaker.GetAnswersAsync` method in the C# SDK, which is `QnAMakerOptions`. The sample you linked (sample [11.qnamaker](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker)) simply has the `QnAMakerOptions` value as null, but you can just fill it in.

---

Inside the OnMessage handler of QnABot.cs in the linked sample, you can do the following:

```cs
            // Create QnAMaker Options -- StrictFilters + Return Top 5 Answers
            var twoStrictFiltersOptions = new QnAMakerOptions
            {
                Top = 5,
                StrictFilters = new Metadata[]
                {
                    new Metadata()
                    {
                        Name = "movie",
                        Value = "disney",
                    },
                    new Metadata()
                    {
                        Name = "home",
                        Value = "floating",
                    },
                },
            };

           // Create your QnAMaker class that will call the QnA service, using the options you created
            var qnaMaker = new QnAMaker(new QnAMakerEndpoint
            {
                KnowledgeBaseId = _configuration["QnAKnowledgebaseId"],
                EndpointKey = _configuration["QnAEndpointKey"],
                Host = _configuration["QnAEndpointHostName"]
            },
            twoStrictFiltersOptions,
            httpClient);

           // Query QnAMaker service
            var response = await qna.GetAnswersAsync(turnContext, twoStrictFiltersOptions);
```

---

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. We are using the Virtual Assistant Template in the BotFramework. I only linked the sample because that's where I was trying to find the information.